# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una suma en asp.net razor pages sin que se borren los datos del formulario?

Tags: c#

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo web y quiero saber ¿cómo puedo realizar una suma en asp.net razor pages sin que se borren los datos del formulario?

```
public  void OnGetPorciento()
 {

     porcentajes.Precio_Detalle= Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["preciodetalle"]);
     porcentajes.Precio_Mayor = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["preciomayor"]);

     porcentajes.Porciento_Detalle = porcentajes.Precio_Detalle + 
     porcentajes.Precio_Mayor;

 }
```

Comment: ¿Y la vista? Entre más detalles en la pregunta, mayores chances de obtener respuesta. Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, lecturas recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.